# Html Email Template not working when sending from mobile

Tags: html, email, email-templates

i have email template and this was configured in firebug Linux its working fine over there , but when that same template configure in mobile phone its not working messing logo and css .
code is like below.

```
<style>span,p,a{font-size:11px;text-transform:uppercase;color:#7f7f7f;font-family:Calibri,Arial,sans-serif;margin:0;padding:0;line-height:11px}</style>
<body>
<div style="width:415px;height:293px">
<div style="width:5px;float:left">
<div style="height:100%;width:100%">
<img style="height:290px" src="http://example.com/line.png" />
</div>
</div>
<div style="width:88%;float:left;padding:5px 0 0 10px">
<p style="clear:both;line-height:12px">
<span style="text-transform:uppercase;font-weight:bold">Example Name</span>
<span style="font-size:10px;vertical-align:top"> |</span>
<span style=""> example name </span>
</p>
<p style="margin:5px 0 3px;padding:0;clear:both;line-height:10px"></p>
<p style="margin:10px 0;padding:0;clear:both;line-height:12px">
<img src="http:www.demo.com/signature_logo/logo.png" alt="Logo" style="width:150px"/>
</p>

</div>
</div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

The code?
Probably you add the CSS code inner `<head></head>`

Most email clients remove all above the `<body>` tag

## EDIT

Now I see your error. in your logo image put correct protocol:

`http:www.demo.com/signature_logo/logo.png` INCORRECT

`http://www.demo.com/signature_logo/logo.png` CORRECT

And put `<style>` tag down the `<body>` tag to maximize compatibility.

Comment: yes my css code not line but its not in head tag , its above the body tag .but what about the logo

Comment: the code? I need to view something to help you. I'm not magician.

Comment: http:www.demo.com/signature_logo/logo.png this my edited code its typo is like in correct way http://www.demo.com/signature_logo/logo.png like that on actual template , but about style sheet i have to check